# How can I determine which smart contract belongs to which vendor/app/etc. I am interacting with?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, dapps, erc-721, erc-1155

Rarible lists (on https://rarible.com/contracts.txt):

```
RC721Sale Contract - 0x131aebbfe55bca0c9eaad4ea24d386c5c082dd58
ERC1155Sale Contract - 0x93f2a75d771628856f37f256da95e99ea28aafbe
ERC721 Nonce Holder Contract - 0xefaefa82be8e827a15c9989417a19107ac9d54af
ERC1155 Nonce Holder Contract - 0x295fe6bc5ad4bdb770d416c066626e4207e10339
Transfer Proxy Contract - 0x4fee7b061c97c9c496b01dbce9cdb10c02f0a0be
Rari mine - 0x3b5d2b254224954547a33cbf753bcaa5eb4b27bd
```

But on the site I see this address associated with ERC-1155 items created Raribles:

```
0xd07dc4262BCDbf85190C01c996b4C06a461d2430
```

Another pseudorandom example:

This is the creator:

```
0x3482549fCa7511267C9Ef7089507c0F16eA1dcC1
```

Of this contract:

```
0xE5c783EE536cf5E63E792988335c4255169be4E1
```

How can I determine if the creator is Rarible/OpenSea/Decentraland/CryptoKitties/etc?

Thank you in advance if you are able to respond (even to say and link to a dup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a smart contract address you can see its creator's address. But beyond that you have very little information inside the blockchain.

To answer questions such as "how can I know whether contract X is the real contract for project Y", basically the only way is to go to the website of project Y and see if they have listed their contract address(es) - most likely they have.

The other way around is trickier: to find out which entity has launched a contract. You can try to look at the transactions from the creator address and analyze them in some way, or you can try googling for the contract/creator address and see if something comes up.

Various external services, such as Etherscan, provide some extra information, but this is centralized data and in theory it shouldn't be trusted.